# Dynamic flag adding DOM elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to add a button, when user click a `span` into a hierchical tree `ul` HTML elements.

This is an example:

```
<ul class="tree">
  <li>
    <span class="li_cat">Food</span>
    <ul class="tree">
      <li>
        <span class="li_cat">Fruit</span>
        <ul class="tree">
          <li>
            <span class="li_cat">Red</span>
            <ul class="tree">
              <li><span class="li_cat">Cherry</span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="li_cat">Yellow</span>
            <ul class="tree">
              <li><span class="li_cat">Banana</span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="li_cat">Meat</span>
        <ul class="tree">
          <li><span class="li_cat">Beef</span></li>
          <li><span class="li_cat">Pork</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

And the jquery code is this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.li_cat', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).html($(this).html()+" <button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i></button>");
});
```

I want to display the button once, but every time I do click on add a new one, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `namespace` at `click` event attached to `document` to reference the `click` event specific to `.li_cat` elements. Check the element `.attr("data-keyname")`, if element does not have a `.attr("data-keyname")`, set a `Boolean` flag at element `.attr("data-keyname")`, use `.html(function)`. Remove delegated `click` event at `document` if all `.li_cat` elements have `.attr("data-keyname")` set to `true`.

```js
$(document).on('click.cat', '.li_cat', function(e) {
  
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  if ($(this).attr("data-clicked") === undefined) {
    $(this).attr("data-clicked", true).html(function(_, html) {
      return html + "<button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'>button</i></button>"
    });
    // if all `.li_cat` elements have `data-clicked` attribute
    if ($(".li_cat[data-clicked]").length === $(".li_cat").length) {
      // remove `click` event listener for `.li_cat` elements
      $(document).off("click.cat")
    }
    
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tree">
  <li>
    <span class="li_cat">Food</span>
    <ul class="tree">
      <li>
        <span class="li_cat">Fruit</span>
        <ul class="tree">
          <li>
            <span class="li_cat">Red</span>
            <ul class="tree">
              <li><span class="li_cat">Cherry</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="li_cat">Yellow</span>
            <ul class="tree">
              <li><span class="li_cat">Banana</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="li_cat">Meat</span>
        <ul class="tree">
          <li><span class="li_cat">Beef</span>
          </li>
          <li><span class="li_cat">Pork</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: OP said to have button only once. So this would work?

Comment: @alessadro See updated post. Included `namespace` at `click` event name, check if to determine if all `.li_cat` elements have `.data().clicked` set, if true, remove delegated `click` event listener from `document` for `.li_cat` elements.

Comment: You have complicated it too much.

Comment: @guest271314 Why should I do that?

Comment: @alessadro If the `click` event is only used to add `<button>` element, once  all of the `.li_cat` elements have been clicked there is no longer a need for the event listener, and event listener handler to be called. If the event handler is not removed, the event handler will still be called when `.li_cat` elements are clicked, even where an additional `<button>` element is not appended to the `.li_cat` element. If you still use the `click` handler for other purposes than to append the `<button>` elements, you can remove last `if` statement.

Comment: @guest271314 is a very nice comment, I'm not a `JavaScript` expert, and I don't see the issue. is "the event handler will still be called when .li_cat elements are clicked." a problem or sort of? I meant the consequences

Comment: It is not a "problem". The consequences would be an event handler possibly being called though is no longer necessary to call the handler. Unnecessary function calls and memory usage. Again, you can remove the last `if` statement if the above is not an issue for you.

Comment: Ah! It's an optimization suggestion, great! "Everyday I learn new things"

Answer (score 1):

First `empty` your `span` and then add the `button` as you want the `button` only once. Also this will make sure that any `button`s added previously will be removed along with there any `events`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.li_cat', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  var spanText = $(this).text();
  $(this).empty();
  $(this).append(spanText);
  $(this).append("<button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i></button>");
});
```

Comment: That code removes the "name", i.e: if I click on `cherry` it will remove "cherry" and put the button, I want to put the button aside of the text

Comment: Glad to help @alessadro. Use of empty() is required in your case in order to avoid having references to old button events as there will tonnes of new buttons on each click added.

Comment: Thanks for your professional feedback and explanation!